# Why doesn't this recur within a mapcat terminate?

Tags: recursion, clojure, compiler-errors, sequence

Why doesn't this `recur` within `mapcat` terminate, whereas the named `fn` call version equivalent does?

```
(def tree [1 [2 [3 5]] [6 [[1 2] [8 [9 10]]]]])

(defn leaves
  [node]
  (mapcat #(if (vector? %) (leaves %) [%]) node))

(leaves tree)
;; => (1 2 3 5 6 1 2 8 9 10)

(defn leaves-with-recur
  [node]
  (mapcat #(if (vector? %) (recur %) [%]) node))

(leaves-with-recur tree)
;; Never terminates
```

If such use of `recur` is a straight-forward no-no, is there any reason why the Clojure compiler should not catch this scenario and warn the programmer, or refuse to compile it even?  As is the case for non-tail position invocations of `recur` for instance.

Comment: Your `recur` is jumping to the anonymous function, not to `leaves-with-recur`.

Comment: Doesn't answer the direct question, but `tree-seq` is good for enumerating leaves of a structure.

Comment: Ack: I was just playing around in the REPL and stumbled across this, there are clearly better ways of traversing the leaves of a tree in Clojure. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#(if (vector? %) (recur %) [%])
```

is a shorthand for

```
(fn [%]
  (if (vector? %)
    (recur %)
    [%]))
```

That `recur` will recurse to this anonymous function, not to any outer one, and since it doesn't change anything, this is an endless loop.

As for warning—the halting problem is known to be unsolvable, and there is a risk of falling into an endless loop at *compile time* even when just trying to put some heuristics into place.

Comment: The shorthand expansion makes what's happening very clear  - thanks!